# From when to when does a 1 round effect last?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, time, initiative, conditions

In Pathfinder with 3pp content allowed, I want to build a soulknife whose mind blade has the *coup de grace* enchantment. It reads:

> Coup de grace weapons are exceptionally dangerous. On a successful critical hit, the foe must succeed on a DC 27 Will save or be paralyzed for 1 round. While this ability does work on creatures that are immune to extra damage from critical hits, it does not work on creatures without an Intelligence score. Bows, crossbows, and slings bestow this ability on their ammunition.

From when to when does the paralysis last? If it lasts from the end of my attack this round to the end of my attack next round, then I could attempt to coup de grace my paralyzed opponent as a full round action next round. But if my understanding of RAW is correct, the 1 round effect would last from my initiative count to the return of my initiative count, meaning by the time I could attack my opponent would no longer by paralyzed.

How does this work?

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47960/8610)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your assumption of RAW is correct.

You would upon scoring a critical hit and them failing their save, paralyze them for one round. The round starts on your initiative count and the paralysis ends just before your following initiative count.

The benefit is that while you yourself aren't deriving a benefit from the paralysis, the targeted creature loses their action for the following round, and it also allows your party members to more easily target the creature while it is paralyzed by the effect of your weapon.

From a GM and a player perspective however, I could see how you yourself would want to derive some form of benefit from an enchanted item such as a Coup de grace weapon, so I could definitely see allowing the paralysis to last from the standard action you made the attack roll with to the attack roll in your next action. This however is up to your GM.

> http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat
>
> Effects that last a certain number of rounds end just before the same
>   initiative count that they began on.